# How to write a has_many relationship in ruby that has array of input in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm learning ruby, and right now I would like to create a has_many relationship with a query that has the input ids contains array of values.

Here is what I'm talking about:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many followers, -> {where (id in (???)), class_name: "Person"

    has_many :students_teachers, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :student_id, dependent: :destroy

    has_many: :teachers, through: :students_teachers
```

And the ids for followers should be the ids of teachers. So I'm not sure how to include the ids of teachers in the query for "followers". Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine (rails 4+)

```
has_many :followers, -> (object) { where(id: object.teacher_ids) }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I need to use all the teachers.ids from the same model since I will get all teachers from that model

Comment: Object refers to the student here. It does use teacher.ids from the student, what you want unless I misunderstood something